# EditText returning null

Tags: android

I don't know whats happening but all the EditTexts are showing to be NUll..Please help as am not able to get its cause.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

String url  = ServerUrl.assignRollNumber;
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
//EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword,editTextEmail,editTextPhone;
Button btnCreateAccount;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    final EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    final EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    final EditText editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
    final EditText editTextEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    final EditText editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount); 

    btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  

               final String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
               final String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
               final String emailid=editTextEmail.getText().toString();
               final String phone = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
               final String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("")||emailid.equals("")||phone.equals(""))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
            }
            if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                final CharSequence[] items={"Email","Phone"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("SEND USER DETAILS VIA");



                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        if("Email".equals(items[which]))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EMAIL SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        else if("Phone".equals(items[which]))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PHONE SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                    }
                });
                builder.show();

            }
        }
    });
    TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
    loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

Here is my XML file for layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">

     <!--  Header Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient">

            <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView  android:src="@drawable/headerlogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
    <!--  Header Ends -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dip"
                android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->

    <!-- Registration Form -->
    <LinearLayout

      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/header">
      <!-- Full Name Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Full Name"/>
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
      <!--  Password Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Password"/>
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
      <!-- Confirm Password Label -->
      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Confirm Password"/>
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Email "/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Phone "/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>


      <!-- Register Button -->
      <Button android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Register New Account"/>
      <!-- Link to Login Screen -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:text="Already has account! Login here"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textColor="#c63a29"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Registration Form Ends -->
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Its always getting null values when i click on one of the radio buttons or even click on register button

Comment: Just to be sure, your xml file is called register.xml?

Comment: **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Comment: @ElDuderino Yes its register.xml.And am not getting any errors.But all these strings are displaying null when printed

Comment: @XaverKapeller Their is no any such error but all strings are printed NULL

Comment: So the EditTexts are NOT null, but there is no text to display, that's what you mean...? So, just to be sure, did you enter anything into these EditTexts? We shouldn't have to guess what your problem is ...

Comment: try taking out `final` from the `Strings`

Comment: @ElDuderino I had entered the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking off the .toString(); after the getText()'s.

Comment: It says to cast String to Editable then

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(userName.getText()));` or try this:
 String userName=!TextUtils.isEmpty(userNamee.getText())?editTextUserName.getText().toString():"";

Comment: Their is no isEmpty() function with a EditText

Answer (score 0):

There is no link between your activity and your xml file: 
add `tools:context="com.example.<applicationname>.RegisterActivity"` to your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.example.<applicationname>.RegisterActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">

     <!--  Header Starts-->
```